# Rules Invoke Event doesn't work

Tags: rules

My aim is to trigger a rule via Ajax.

Until now I create a custom module called "*iscrizione*"

Here my iscrizione.rules.inc

```
function iscrizione_rules_event_info() {    
$items = array();

$items['iscrizione_evento'] = array(
  'label' => 'Iscrizione all\'evento',
  'group' => t('Links'),
  'variables' => array(
    'path' => array(
      'type' => 'array',
      'label' => t('Path accessed'),
      'description' => t('The path which has just been accessed.'),
    ),
    'account' => array(
      'type' => 'user',
      'label' => t('updated user'),
    ),
  ),
);

return $items; 
}
```

Here my iscrizione.module

```
function iscrizione_menu() {
$items = array();

$items['conferma/%'] = array(
'title' => 'Conferma Iscrizione',
'page callback' => 'iscrizione_evento',
'page arguments' => array(1),
'access arguments' => array('access content'),
);

return $items;
}

function iscrizione_evento($arg) {
echo $arg;
// rules_invoke_component('rules_stampa_messaggio', $arg);
rules_invoke_event('rules_iscrizione_iscrizione_evento', $arg);
}
```

I tried both functions (invoke event and component), but if I type the url I can see only the $arg printed.

No action was fired (as actions I put " 
Show a message on the site" and a "Create entity")

Any help?

Comment: If this is exact code from your module, then you're calling wrong rule in `rules_invoke_event()`. The rule name should be `iscrizione_evento`. i.e. `rules_invoke_event('iscrizione_evento', $arg);`. Check [this link](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/124547/678).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within `$items` of your `iscrizione_rules_event_info()`, you used `iscrizione_evento`. So in your `iscrizione.module` you should refer to that. Try this variation of it:

```
function iscrizione_menu() {
$items = array();

$items['conferma/%'] = array(
'title' => 'Conferma Iscrizione',
'page callback' => 'iscrizione_evento',
'page arguments' => array(1),
'access arguments' => array('access content'),
);

return $items;
}

function iscrizione_evento($arg) {
echo $arg;
// rules_invoke_component('rules_stampa_messaggio', $arg);
rules_invoke_event('iscrizione_evento', $arg);
}
```

Maybe it would also help if you'd slightly adapt the **readability** of your code, by not using `iscrizione_evento` for different things. How about, eg, these variations of it:

- `menu_iscrizione_evento`.
- `rules_event_iscrizione`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, from the examples I read in other pages I understood that the rules_invoke_event first argument was rules-machinename + rules_event-machinename. Now is working, thanks a lot! P.S. I modified the name as iscrizione_module and rules_event_iscrizione, more readable now ;)

Answer (score 2):

Using the accepted answer I fixed my code, but then I ran into another problem, i.e.:

> Notice: Undefined index: name in EntityMetadataWrapper->debugIdentifierLocation() (linea 246 di /home/contactbologna/public_html/sites/all/modules/entity/in‌​cludes/entity.wrappe‌​r.inc).

This new problem was around the variables type on event info.

The final version of the code now looks like this:

```
function iscrizione_module_menu() {
  $items['conferma/%'] = array(
  'title' => 'Conferma Iscrizione',
  'page callback' => 'iscrizione_evento_callback',
  'page arguments' => array(1),
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
);
return $items;
}

function iscrizione_evento_callback($arg) {
//global $user;
if (user_is_logged_in()) 
{ 
  $user = user_uid_optional_load(); 
}
$path[] = $arg;
// rules_invoke_component('rules_stampa_messaggio', $arg);
rules_invoke_event('rules_event_iscrizione', $path, $user);
}
```

and

```
function iscrizione_module_rules_event_info() {
  $items = array();
  $items['rules_event_iscrizione'] = array(
    'label' => 'Iscrizione all\'evento',
    'group' => t('Links'),
    'variables' => array(
      'path' => array(
        'type' => 'array',
        'label' => t('Path accessed'),
        'description' => t('The path which has just been accessed.'),
      ),
      'account' => array(
        'type' => 'user',
        'label' => t('updated user'),
      ),
    ),
  );
return $items;
}
```